# Understanding many to many mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am referring to the example at - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/ **Employees** can attend many **Meetings** and Meetings 
can be attended by many Employees.

Let the owning class be Employee. The many to many mapping code inside Employee will be -

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})  
@JoinTable(name="EMPLOYEE_MEETING",   
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")},   
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MEETING_ID")})  
private Set<Meeting> meetings = new HashSet<Meeting>();
```

I looked at several other examples and documentation, but I am still not sure how this works. I don't think I fully understand what joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns do.

`joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")}` - Does this line only tell hibernate 
that Employee id of employee joins employee id of the mapping table ?

`inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MEETING_ID")})` ? Does this line only tell hibernate to join Employee id to the Meeting_Id column in the link table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the actual annotation is saying is that Hibernate should create an intermediate join table. One column of this table should map to the column on your `Employee` table called `Employee_ID` (that's your `joinColumns` parameter), and the other column should map to the column on your `Meeting` table called `Meeting_ID` (that's your `inverseJoinColumns` parameter).

The `joinColumns` parameter should specify the PK of the owning entity (in this case your Employee object), while the `inverseJoinColumn` specifies the PK of the non-owning  entity.

Note that you don't always have to just specify your join columns as PK's, but it makes sense because uniqueness is enforced and its kind of the point of a PK. You can also have multiple join columns forming a composite key on either side of the relationship within the join table.

You seem to have a handle on how the relationships are set up but I'll say this for the benefit of people coming here from Google. In a bidirectional relationship you have to specify which side of the relationship 'owns' the relationship. While you can have a bidirectional cascade as well, you usually only access the non-owning object through the owning one. So you don't generally access a `Meeting` object directly, you access it through a `Employee` object. This becomes more important in a uni-directional relationship but it can cause a few problems in a bidirectional relationship in determining what you want to cascade.

For example, if you decide that if you delete a `Meeting`, you don't want the deletion to cascade to the join table, you need to change your `CascadeType` in your `Meeting` class.

If you want me to expand on my explanation please let me know.

Comment: Thanks James. It seems that `inverseJoinColumns` is just a misnomer and that nothing is being inverted. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yeah, nothing is inverted, its just the inverse side of the mapping

Comment: Thanks James. Btw, was J2EE a part of your college curriculum ?

Comment: Not really, I learned it in my final year doing an industry project with the company that ended up hiring me.

Comment: So, which aspects of J2EE are you most familiar with ? Eg. Hibernate, Spring, JSP, Servlet etc. Sorry if this sounds like an interview. I am only curious to know how much a person can learn in a year with a full-time job.

Comment: Spring and Hibernate mostly, with a touch of JSP, but I prefer RESTful HTML with jQuery. I'm fairly confidant with Spring and Hibernate, and you learn a metric ton more when you are surrounded by the technologies every day compared to at uni.